# Как получить список функций в python

Tags: python, массивы, list, списки

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно получить список всех функций в программе ?

К примеру у меня есть несколько функций в программе: `oh()`, `hello()`, `there()`,
которые что-то делают, как мне получить список по типу `["oh", "hello", "there"]`?

Comment: Просто уберите кавычки: [oh, hello, there]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[name for (name , obj) in vars().items()
     if hasattr(obj, "__class__") and obj.__class__.__name__ == "function"]
```

Обяснение:

`vars()` - словарь *имен переменных* (т. е. тоже имен *функций*) и к ним принадлежащих *объектов*.

`vars().items()` - пары *имен* и к ним принадлежащих *объектов*.

Функции отличаются от других объектов тем, что они объекты *класса функций*, т. е. имеют атрибут `__class__`, и атрибут `__name__` этого класса у них равен строке `"function"`.

---

*Пример использования:*

```
def oh():
    pass

def hello(name):
    pass

def there(x, y):
    pass

a = 7
b = "Hello"

func_list = [name for (name , obj) in vars().items()
                 if hasattr(obj, "__class__") and obj.__class__.__name__ == "function"]

print(func_list)
```

*Вывод:*

> ```
> ['oh', 'hello', 'there']
> ```

Comment: Спасибо большое )

Comment: Но есть вопрос, можно ли как то получить комментарий функции который в тройных ковычках """комментарий""" ?

Comment: Да, это возможно. Пожалуйста, пометите мой ответ «принятым» (клик на галочку), когда изложенное в нём решение вам помогло.

Comment: Комментарий функции получите как `obj.__doc__` - например `func_list = [(name, obj.__doc__) for (name , obj) in vars().items()  if hasattr(obj, "__class__") and obj.__class__.__name__ == "function"]`.